# Initialize static constant member variable in nested class

Tags: c++

Given codes in language C++

```
/* file xxx.hpp */

class A
{
};

class B
{
private:
    class C
    {
        static const A a;
    };
};
```

How can I initialize the static constant member variable `A a` in nested class C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the cpp file with code that is to be compiled you should add `const A B::C::a = {};`.
The initializer (be it an initializer list in {...} for POD classes or aggregate types or a single constant value for built-in types) is optional - if it's not specified, a default constructor will be called for `a`. In case of primitive types, it should be set to 0.

**updated:**

As David has greatly remarked below, some compilers issue warnings when no initializer is specified for a static member definition. If there are some data members in `class A` and no initializer during definition of `a` is specified, my g++ 4.6.3 compiler issues the following warning (that is by default is treated as error):

> test.cpp:26:9: error: uninitialized const ‘B::C::a’ [-fpermissive]
>
> test.cpp:6:7: note: ‘const class A’ has no user-provided default
>
> constructor test.cpp:11:8: note: and the implicitly-defined constructor does not initialize ‘int A::test’

Comment: Some compilers will warn if the value is not specified (even though the standard guarantees that the type will be *value-initialized*)

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to exactly one `.cpp`:

```
const A B::C::a;
```

Note that the posted code was only a *declaration*: this is the actual definition and initialisation.

Answer (score 3):

Like you would a regular `static` member.

In your implementation file:

```
const A B::C::a;
```

Comment: @MarceloCantos: If the declaration says that it is const, then the definition must adhere to it

Answer (score 3):

Initialization of static member variables is always performed in the definition of the variable, which has to be in a single translation unit within your program:

```
const A B::C::a = {};
```

Answer (score 3):

In the source file (xxx.cpp), define the variable:

```
const A B::C::a;
```